# JSON Serialization Performance issue Web API

Tags: json, performance, asp.net-web-api, json.net

We have an asp.net web API application, where when a POST API is invoked it takes 30 seconds to hit the first statement inside the API. I understand the time taken in mainly in de-serializing the object from request body. We use Newtonsoft json, with the default contract resolver.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

The Json object has 25 departments -> each department an array of 5 year objects > each year having an array of months (12 objects) -> each month is an object with 15 properties

Interesting part is the performance delay happens only in a specific environment. While there is no issue in my local environment, with copy of the same data. I can try the suggested performance improvement for newtonsoft (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm), but before that I would expect the same issue to happen in my local as well.

Appreciate any help!

---

Update

DefaultContractResolver.DynamicCodeGeneration is set to True in both my local and the other environment.

Result of

`public class Model { public string Foo { get; set; }`

```
((JsonObjectContract)contractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(Model))).Properties[0].ValueProvider.GetType()
```

is DynamicValueProvider in both my local and the other environment.

Comment: Have you tried profiling?  What are the results?  What is the value of [`DefaultContractResolver.DynamicCodeGeneration`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_DynamicCodeGeneration.htm) on your computer and in the specific environment?

Comment: Also, if you have simple model with one property, say `public class Model { public string Foo { get; set; }`, and you do `((JsonObjectContract)contractResolver.ResolveContract(typeof(Model))).Properties[0].ValueProvider.GetType()`, what is the actual, concrete type?  Is it `DynamicValueProvider`, `ReflectionValueProvider` or `ExpressionValueProvider`?

Comment: @dbc have added the results to the question, the values are same in both the environments. I didn't try profiling as I'm unable to replicate the issue locally.

Comment: `DynamicCodeGeneration` and `ValueProvider` are the things that are most obviously platform+machine specific inside Json.NET that could affect performance.  Are you certain you are using the same version of Json.NET?  Same framework versions?  Same 32- vs 64-it settings?  If the build & run environments are the same I doubt there's much more help we can give without more information.

Comment: Still, absent a better idea, it wouldn't hurt to try caching and reusing a static `DefaultContractResolver` as recommended by https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver to see if that helps.

Comment: @dbc The issue is when the de-serialization happens (internally) for the Web API Post body, I assume there will be only one instance of DefaultContractResolver used. Let me dig deeper and see. Thanks!

Comment: 22,500 properties does not seem like a particularly large amount of JSON that it would cause performance problems.  Are you sure this is a JSON deserialization issue and not some other issue with that environment?  Does this problem happen with other methods in the API or just this one?  Have you tried creating another method for testing purposes that uses, say, XML instead of JSON to see whether it has the same issue?

Comment: Analyzing further we noticed the requests are taking <1 sec if we access the API directly from the server. We are checking if any load balance/WAF is causing the delay, will update here once we find the cause.. Seems the issue is not with the application itself. Thanks for your help!